# How to create local nuget packages for docker?

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, nuget

I want to create local nuget package for docker
whene in nuget.config, add "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages" for nuget repository, on runtime, docker add "src" at the first of address and can't find "src\C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages"

how to create local nuget package on "localhost:8000"?

my Dockerfile is :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY "solution-name.sln" "PadCMS.sln"

COPY "BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.Common/Core.Common.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.Common/Core.Common.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.WebApi/Core.WebApi.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.WebApi/Core.WebApi.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/Core/Core/Core.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/Core/Core/Core.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/Devspaces.Support/Devspaces.Support.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/Devspaces.Support/Devspaces.Support.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus/EventBus.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus/EventBus.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusRabbitMQ/EventBusRabbitMQ.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusRabbitMQ/EventBusRabbitMQ.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusServiceBus/EventBusServiceBus.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusServiceBus/EventBusServiceBus.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/IntegrationEventLogEF/IntegrationEventLogEF.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/IntegrationEventLogEF/IntegrationEventLogEF.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/WebHostCustomization/WebHost.Customization/WebHost.Customization.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/WebHostCustomization/WebHost.Customization/WebHos

COPY "NuGet.config" "NuGet.config"

RUN dotnet restore "PadCMS.sln"


COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Services/Accounting/Accounting.API
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Accounting.API.dll"]
```

Comment: Your docker container doesn't have access to your normal filesystem, so it can't access `C:\..` (even if the paths were correct). What you want to do is to include the nuget packages in some directory that you `COPY` into the container. If you add the path to that directory inside the container into your `NuGet.Config`, then `dotnet` should able to use that package source.

Answer (score 0):

1. you cant use your downloaded package in `c:\...` because is filesystem.
2. to create local NuGet package repository you can use [BaGet](https://loic-sharma.github.io/BaGet/). BaGet also support run with docker and have [documentation](https://loic-sharma.github.io/BaGet/installation/docker/) about it.
   after installation you must upload all package your application use to local nuget repository.then need put`nuget.config` file in application folder to only use local nuget repository like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="local" value="your local address" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

but I don't recommend this and recommend use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69449323/5360463)

Comment: i had used package in "c:\program file\..." but docker is reading from "src\c:\..." so that can't find them
also i'm installed BaGet on docker, but docker run nuget/findbyid, BaGet has not this address

Comment: Can you please send a sample?

Comment: @rezamalekmohamadi you cant use c:\ . for BaGet I make answer complete

Comment: yes but whene i'm running docker-compose, docker added "src" at the first of address automatic, then can't find it