# why the dotnet project is not published in the docker?

Tags: docker, .net-core, nuget

I have dotnet core solution contains some microservice project,
whene I'm trying to publish my projects on dokcer, I'm get some errors

my dockerfile is :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj", "Services/Identity/Identity.API/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/Core/Core/Core.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/Core/Core/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.Common/Core.Common.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.Common/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/WebHostCustomization/WebHost.Customization/WebHost.Customization.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/WebHostCustomization/WebHost.Customization/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.WebApi/Core.WebApi.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.WebApi/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/EventBus/IntegrationEventLogEF/IntegrationEventLogEF.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/IntegrationEventLogEF/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus/EventBus.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusRabbitMQ/EventBusRabbitMQ.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusRabbitMQ/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/Identity/Identity.API"
RUN dotnet build "Identity.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Identity.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Identity.API.dll"]
```

and my output is :

```
#19 240.8   Restored /src/BuildingBlocks/WebHostCustomization/WebHost.Customization/WebHost.Customization.csproj (in 43.14 sec).
#19 241.0   Restored /src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/IntegrationEventLogEF/IntegrationEventLogEF.csproj (in 148 ms).
#19 241.1   Restored /src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusRabbitMQ/EventBusRabbitMQ.csproj (in 40 ms).
#19 275.6   Failed to download package 'System.Text.Json.4.7.2' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.json/4.7.2/system.text.json.4.7.2.nupkg'.
#19 275.6   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.json/4.7.2/system.text.json.4.7.2.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#19 275.6     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#19 282.3   Failed to download package 'AutoMapper.9.0.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/automapper/9.0.0/automapper.9.0.0.nupkg'.
#19 282.3   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/automapper/9.0.0/automapper.9.0.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#19 282.3     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#19 282.7   Failed to download package 'System.Threading.4.0.11' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.threading/4.0.11/system.threading.4.0.11.nupkg'.
#19 282.7   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.threading/4.0.11/system.threading.4.0.11.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#19 282.7     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#19 284.4   Failed to download package 'System.Collections.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.collections/4.3.0/system.collections.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#19 284.4   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.collections/4.3.0/system.collections.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#19 284.4     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#19 287.3   Failed to download package 'System.Diagnostics.Process.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.process/4.3.0/system.diagnostics.process.4.3.0.nupkg'.
#19 287.3   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.process/4.3.0/system.diagnostics.process.4.3.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#19 287.3     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#19 288.2   Restored /src/BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.Common/Core.Common.csproj (in 47.12 sec).
#19 288.8   Failed to download package 'System.ComponentModel.4.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.componentmodel/4.0.1/system.componentmodel.4.0.1.nupkg'.
#19 288.8   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.componentmodel/4.0.1/system.componentmodel.4.0.1.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#19 288.8     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#19 289.5   Failed to download package 'System.Diagnostics.Process.4.1.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.process/4.1.0/system.diagnostics.process.4.1.0.nupkg'.
#19 289.5   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.process/4.1.0/system.diagnostics.process.4.1.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#19 289.5     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#19 290.0   Failed to download package 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations.4.5.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.componentmodel.annotations/4.5.0/system.componentmodel.annotations.4.5.0.nupkg'.
#19 290.0   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.componentmodel.annotations/4.5.0/system.componentmodel.annotations.4.5.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#19 290.0     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#19 291.1   Failed to download package 'System.Text.Encoding.4.0.11' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.encoding/4.0.11/system.text.encoding.4.0.11.nupkg'.
#19 291.1   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.encoding/4.0.11/system.text.encoding.4.0.11.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#19 291.1     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#19 293.1   Failed to download package 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.16.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.applicationinsights.windowsserver.telemetrychannel/2.16.0/microsoft.applicationinsights.windowsserver.telemetrychannel.2.16.0.nupkg'.
#19 293.1   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.applicationinsights.windowsserver.telemetrychannel/2.16.0/microsoft.applicationinsights.windowsserver.telemetrychannel.2.16.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#19 293.1     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#19 295.2   Failed to download package 'System.Memory.4.5.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.memory/4.5.1/system.memory.4.5.1.nupkg'.
#19 295.2   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.memory/4.5.1/system.memory.4.5.1.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#19 295.2     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#19 297.2   Failed to download package 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations.4.1.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.componentmodel.annotations/4.1.0/system.componentmodel.annotations.4.1.0.nupkg'.
#19 297.2   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.componentmodel.annotations/4.1.0/system.componentmodel.annotations.4.1.0.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#19 297.2     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#19 300.5   Failed to download package 'System.IO.FileSystem.4.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.io.filesystem/4.0.1/system.io.filesystem.4.0.1.nupkg'.
#19 300.5   The download of 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.io.filesystem/4.0.1/system.io.filesystem.4.0.1.nupkg' timed out because no data was received for 60000ms.
#19 300.5     Exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' was thrown.
#19 1287.9   Restored /src/Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj (in 18.19 min).
#19 DONE 1290.5s
```

When I type the address

> https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.io.filesystem/4.0.1/system.io.filesystem.4.0.1.nupkg

In the browser, the package is downloaded but Docker can not download from the same address

my os is windows 10, and I'm using docker desktop on it to build image,

I created the image in both ways, both by Visual Studio and Docker Command(docker-compose up)
I encountered the same problem in both ways

maybe problem is ssl
because an other error message is :

```
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.hosting.abstractions/index.json'.
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
```

how to resolve it

Comment: Are you building the docker image from a build agent, that may be blocked by firewall or is it on the same machine your are working with?

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen only to the filesystem package, please add your do let configuration, installation process, version, host machine details, etc... (To original question as *EDIT*)

Comment: are you have slow internet speed ?

Comment: my internet speed is good,

Comment: @rezamalekmohamadi In my experiment good for this is 16mb or more

Comment: maybe problem is ssl because an other error message is :
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.hosting.abstractions/index.json'.
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

Comment: @rezamalekmohamadi I have same error and fix it with increase internet speed

Comment: Can you try a `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0` and `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0` to make sure you have the latest image? There have been some CA issues in April that should have been resolved in newer images.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem reason of is my slow internet speed. must use `--disable-parallel` flag in dotnet restore command
like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj", "Services/Identity/Identity.API/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/Core/Core/Core.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/Core/Core/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.Common/Core.Common.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.Common/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/WebHostCustomization/WebHost.Customization/WebHost.Customization.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/WebHostCustomization/WebHost.Customization/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.WebApi/Core.WebApi.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/Core/Core.WebApi/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/EventBus/IntegrationEventLogEF/IntegrationEventLogEF.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/IntegrationEventLogEF/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus/EventBus.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusRabbitMQ/EventBusRabbitMQ.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusRabbitMQ/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj" --disable-parallel
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/Identity/Identity.API"
RUN dotnet build "Identity.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Identity.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Identity.API.dll"]
```

disadvantage of this flag is your docker build time rise lot